# Scale a UIView with animation but without Transform

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uikit

I try to scale a `UIView` with a circle shape to make it double in size when I click on it.

my final target is to reproduce the apple music behavior:
-When you click on a circle, it grows and pushes other circles around.

I m trying to achieve this with `UIKit` dynamics but the first problem is that animating a scale without `CATransform` (it doesn't work with collisions) fails.

at the end of the animation, even if width and height are 100,
the final shape is a rectangle...

here is my code

```
func ballTapped(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .Ended {
            collision.removeItem(sender.view!)
            let item = sender.view!
            var theFrame = item.frame
            theFrame.size.height = 100
            theFrame.size.width = 100
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
                    item.frame = theFrame
                }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
                    self.collision.addItem(sender.view!)
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{

                         [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 delay: 0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction |UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

                             _iCarouselCarVW.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.001, 0.001);
                             _iCarBackView.hidden = YES;
                             NSLog(@"%f",self.view.frame.size.width);
                             _iCarouselCenterConstant.constant = self.view.frame.size.width/2 + 50;
                             [self.iCarouselCarVW setCurrentItemIndex:0];
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished)
                          {


                          }];

                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // Called on parent view
                     }];
```